# Event on leaving Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to reduce the opacity on some divs if I hover another div, but if I stop hovering the div the opacity should be changed back to `1` again.

HTML

```
<div id="feld1" onmouseover="show1()"> </div>
<div id="feld2" onmouseover="show2()"> </div>
<div id="feld3" onmouseover="show3()"> </div>
```

JS

```
function show1() {
  if ($('#feld1:hover').length != 0) {
    document.getElementById("feld2").style.opacity = 0.1;
    document.getElementById("feld3").style.opacity = 0.1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("feld2").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("feld3").style.opacity = 1;   
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how it will work?

Comment: I think you want [mouseout event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp)

Comment: You have onmouseleave as well http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseleave.asp

Comment: You can do this with CSS. `#feld1:hover ~ div[id^=feld] { opacity: 0.1 }` https://jsfiddle.net/qk1ymooo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got it...

```
document.getElementById("feld1").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
document.getElementById("feld1").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};

function mouseOver() {

    document.getElementById("feld2").style.opacity = 0.1;
    document.getElementById("feld3").style.opacity = 0.1;
}

function mouseOut() {
     document.getElementById("feld2").style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById("feld3").style.opacity = 1; 
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("feld1").onmouseover = mouseOver;` Don't need the wrapping function. Make sure you do not include the `()`.